# looping and date growing 7 days according in php

Tags: php

I want to enter the data with looping and date growing 7 days according total input events
For example, on my form data input like this :

```
Input Date  : 2015-11-27
Input Event : Meeting
Total Event : 3
```

This is my PHP code to insert with looping :

```
$date= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));    
$getDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'));
$event = $_POST['event'];
$ttl_event = $_POST['ttl_event'];

for ($i = 0; $i < $ttl_event; $i++) {  
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule values('','$getDate','$event')")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

And then finally in table, i want to like this :

```
id |     date    |   event
1    2015-11-27    Meeting 
2    2015-12-04    Metting 
3    2015-12-11    Meeting
```

now, i always error with date always "2015-12-04" :(

please, correct my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate future dates inside the loop, and increment the addition for each iteration. Meaning you wanna do +0, +7, +14...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ttl_event; $i++) {  
  $getDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' +'.($i*7).'days'));
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule values('','$getDate','$event')") 
                                                     ^ are you sure about this ?

  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Or you can write it like that

```
$getDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.($i*7).'days', $date));
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php

Comment: thanks, it work. but im correct to : $getDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' + '.(($i)*7).' days')); because add 7 days start second row and next...

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted to add straight away ! Glad you fixed it. Good luck